# More elegant if statement handling

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose I have a list of N tuples, with the tuples having first a string, and then a float such as `('cat', 0.5)`. They are organized in such a way so that the earlier in the list they appear, the greater the size of the float for the second element.

Let's say I want to accomplish the following:

1. Test if the list of tuples contains only one tuple
2. Test if the first element of the list of tuples is a string
3. If the list of tuples contains more than one tuple, is the float for the first tuple at least twice as large as the float of the second tuple?

If 1, 2 are true or 2, 3 are true then the test passes.

I tried coding something like this:

```
if isinstance(tuples[0][0],str):
    if len(tuples) > 1:
        if tuples[0][1] > 2 * tuples[1][1]:
            print('Success')
    elif len(tuples) == 1:
        print('Success')
```

Is there a less code-smelly way of doing this, without having to code the success condition twice?

Comment: increment a counter of test passes and if thats greater or equal to two then you have your success

Comment: `if <2> and (<1> or <3>)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to store the value of the last processed float in order to check your 3rd condition (*the float of the N-th tuple is >= the float of the N+1-th tuple*).

If you initialize such variable to infinity, you can avoid checking explicitly for your 1st condition (*the list of tuples contains only one tuple*).

So in your code you just check the 2nd condition (*the first element of the list of tuples is a string*) and the 3rd one:

```
def check(tuples):

  last_value = float("inf")

  for text, value in tuples:

    if not isinstance(text, str):
      return False

    if last_value < value * 2:
      return False

    last_value = value

  return True

if check(tuples):
  print("Success")
```